# The new Word for Mac version (15.17.1) is not opening docs in SharePoint library

Tags: 2010, word

Our user is trying to open Word for Mac documents in a standard SharePoint 2010 library.

He upgraded Word for Mac a few weeks ago, to the 15.17.1 version. Before, he could work in collaborative mode in SharePoint which is essential for our large, cross-country editing team.

However, now no matter what browser he uses, nor if he uses the down arrow and opens in Word function, he can't open a document. It opens Word, but gives a grey, no document opened, Word program. He can download, make changes, and send the doc in email back to the team, so will do that this weekend.

Has anybody heard of an incompatibility between this new version and SharePoint? Any solutions? Could it just be a trusted sites issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm whenter the option of Allow plug-ins is enabled by going to Safari > Preferences > Secruity > Internet plug-ins > Allow plug-ins? If it is disabled, all installed plug-ins will not appear under Help > Installed Plug-ins including SharePoint Browser plug-in. Could you confirm the setting, enabled it if it is disabled and ensure SharePoint site is set to Allowed as follow?

Comment: For Sharepoint 2010 Office seems to need A plugin for Sharepoint to open and edit documents.